# Vertical Inverse scrolling

Tags: usability, user-research, scrolling

I have visited the site http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/ . There you can see **horizontal scrolling** and in level 4, you can see the **Inverse vertical scrolling**. When I scroll back, it makes me little bit confusing. Will this type of **"Inverse vertical scrolling."** affect the normal users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse the usability of works of art for "best practice".

While it's a great implementation of scroll-hijacking, this is not meant to be "best practice".

**Generally speaking, you want to stick to patterns that the user is already used to.**

This does not include inverted scrolling.

Any time you want to introduce a new pattern, it takes time for users to get used to it. And on top of that, it takes effort. The user must want to learn. Whether that's because they think the pattern is good and want to get used to it, or because they have to get used to it because there is no other way to get to what they want.

Point is, don't do it unless you're 100% sure it fits your site. (a good example is the one you linked, where scrolling was linked through "progress" down a set path.)

Comment: Most people want to stick with patterns that already used. I am asking how these new navigation methods will cover or affect the normal user.

Comment: No you're not. You're asking if this is good practice. Literally. And it isn't. Perhaps rephrase your initial question a bit, so others don't give you the "wrong answer". And reworded, my answer comes down to "it will negatively affect the user's experience". You'd have to teach them this feature from the ground scratch, which takes time, exposure, effort.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I have edited the question. So you are saying that it will take time to reach the normal user. Right?. Using this type of scrolling for normal user will not enhance UX. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. Any time you want to introduce a new pattern, it takes time for users to get used to it. And on top of that, it takes effort. The user must *want* to learn. Whether that's because they think the pattern is good and want to get used to it, or because they *have to* get used to it because there is no other way to get to what they *want*. Point is, don't do it unless you're 100% sure it fits your site. (a good example is the one you linked, where scrolling was linked through "progress" down a set path.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very clear. Thanks again for making me to learn new thing.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could be of assistance. Keep in mind, always keep things *easy* for the user. Use what they know, and preferably things they don't even have to think about.

Comment: Yes sure. Will do the easy things that user can understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
the question changed so the answer isn't relevant anymore

in general no.

but here the scrolling is used to advance the "story".

it's more like navigating a video/timeline (the inverse apparent motion is not really relevant, it could be diagonal or whatever; you'll also notice that when you change direction of the scroll, the character changes direction).

in the context of the site you linked it's pretty clear that the scroll is not used as a standard control so the user has lowered expectations about the scroll (it could be argued that the basic pattern pattern is still there though: scroll up to go backwards and down to go forward in the "document")

Comment: Thanks, But what I am expecting is, will these type of new navigation will be easy for normal user

Comment: added some more details